# How to Keep Screen On For specific condition, even after we left that activity(window)?

Tags: android, kotlin, timeout, screen

Using `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)`, It can only allow for one activity. If I switch to another activity than screen will goes off.

My requirement is : If toggle button enable - screen will not off, if disable screen can goes off THROUGHOUT the application.

WAKE_LOCK is not recommended for android 11 and 12 as of now so rather than this options are welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Write the value of that setting to shared preferences.  Load it in the new activity, and have every activity set that flag in their onCreate if the setting is on.

Comment: @GabeSechan there's almost 40 activities in the app

Comment: Then do it 40 times.  Or write a MyBaseActivity that does it once, and have everyone else inherit from MyBaseActivity instead of Activity.  I'm shocked you have 40 Activities and haven't long since done that.